# How to make these buttons work properly

Tags: javascript

I want my HTML button will add one each time it is clicked but for some reason which I can't find, both the **Yes** and **No** button will add to the **No** box.... why?

```
<h3>Did this Help?</h3>
<br>
<form>
   <input type="text" id="Yes" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Yes" />
</form>

<br>
<br>

<form>
   <input type="text" id="No" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="No" />
</form>

<script>


function incrementValue(yes)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('Yes').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('Yes').value = value;
}

function incrementValue(No)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('No').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('No').value = value;
}
```

Comment: well you can't have two methods named the same thing. The second one overrides the first.

Answer (score 1):

> both the **Yes** and **No** button will add to the **No** box.... why?

This is because the function names are same, your second function is overriding the first function.

You do not need to write same function twice. Just pass `id` to the function in the `button` like the following way:

```js
function incrementValue(id){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

```html
<h3>Did this Help?</h3>
<br>
<form>
   <input type="text" id="Yes" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue('Yes')" value="Yes" />
</form>

<br>
<br>

<form>
   <input type="text" id="No" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue('No')" value="No" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that you are using two times the same function `incrementValue`, so it will use the last one defined : the one updating the 'No' field.

I updated your function so that it receives a parameter : the id of the button. So you can just use it to increment the right value.

```js
function incrementValue(buttonId)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(buttonId).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById(buttonId).value = value;
}
```

```html
<h3>Did this Help?</h3>
<br>
<form>
   <input type="text" id="Yes" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue('Yes')" value="Yes" />
</form>

<br>
<br>

<form>
   <input type="text" id="No" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue('No')" value="No" />
</form>
```